# How can I use my Raspberry Pi 4 as a bluetooth receiver?

Tags: bluetooth, raspberry-pi

Is it possible to configure my RPi so that I can connect to it with my mobile phone via Bluetooth, for example to play songs? The RPi would then be connected to speakers with an AUX cable.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Advanced Audio Distribution Profile (A2DP) is the [Bluetooth Profile](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/profiles-overview/) that you need. If you want the RPi to be the speaker then it will be in the *audio sink* role. Searching the internet for these terms got a large number of results. As an example, this one:

http://www.knight-of-pi.org/finally-raspberry-pi-3b-buster-as-bluetooth-audio-sink/

From that page, someone recommends:

https://github.com/gmsoft-tuxicoman/bt-audio